# How to view/debug cache management in dev environment?

Tags: caching, symfony

I just start to learn how Symfony2 Reverse Proxy works and I read all doc about it. 
The cache is designed to work in prod environment, but while I'm developing my app (dev env), setting exiration or validation models, or others headers related to http cache trough awsome sf2 api. How to view/debug cache info in dev environment? Is Posible?

Answer (score 0):

For now, the only debug information you can have is the HTTP header named "X-Symfony-Cache". It contains information about hits and misses.

See the documentation to have (few) more informations: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_cache.html#symfony2-reverse-proxy